# Here sdk navigation direction arrows are below Z-Index 0

Tags: here-api

I'm drawing some `MapPolyline` on the map and then using the map for navigation. Sadly, the arrows showing the direction to take at the next turn is bellow the `MapPolyline`. I have set the `ZIndex` of the `polyline` to 0 but it does not solve the issue.

How to have the direction arrow above the `MapPolyline`?

Snapshot of the issue:

[image: arrow below polyline]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `MapObject#setOverlayType(MapOverlayType)`. Note that this must be called on the `MapPolyline` before it is added to a `Map`. More info here: [Map Rendering Order](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/map-render-order.html)

Comment: .setOverlayType(MapOverlayType.ROAD_OVERLAY) does what I want. Thank you

Comment: can we disable \ hide these arrows at all?